# Usage of master theorem for solving recursions

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I know that master theorem is used for the recurrence relations of the form:

T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)

But in my question, i am supposed to solve the following recurrence relation by using master theorem:

T(n) = 2T(n/7) + 5T(n/8) + n

Can i take f(n)=n and since f(n)=Θ(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>), i say T(n) is O(nlogn)? But if i do this, i neglect the fact that the relation must be of the form T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n). What should i do? Thanks

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319535/solving-a-recurrence-relation-using-master-method. Please do not cross-post immediately on two stackexchange sites. Wait for a few days, and if you do not get an answer, you can post at another place with links to the other question in both posts.

Comment: For this kind of recurrence you have to expand things by hand and look for some patterns. It is ugly.

Comment: You can also "guess" the right answer and prove the result by induction.

Answer (score 5):

You may solve this recurrence by using the Akra-Bazzi method, which generalizes the master theorem and allows solving recurrences of the form

$T(n)= \sum\limits_{i = 1}^k {a_i T(n/b_i) + f(n)}$

You need to solve for $p$ the equation

$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^k {a_i b_i^{-p} = 1}$

and the solution to the recurrence can be obtained exactly as in the master theorem, but you must compare $f(n)$ with $n^p$ instead of $n^{\lg_b a}$.

For your recurrence, $p = 0.954101 \quad$ so that $f(n) = n \quad $ dominates $n^p = n^{0.954101}$ and therefore, $T(n) = O(n) \quad$ (you may want to verify that the master theorem regularity condition also holds).

Akra and Bazzi also proved a more general [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

Comment: How do you find `p`?

Comment: Usually, you are not able to find a closed-form solution for $p$, so you have to solve numerically.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can easily get $T(n)=O(n\log n)$, since $2T(n/7)+5T(n/8)\le 7T(n/7)$, and the master theorem gives you that $S(n)=7S(n/7)+n$ is $\Theta(n\log n)$.

The question is, can you do better - that is to prove that $T(n)=\Theta(n)$. I think that if you follow the proof of the master theorem, you will be able to conclude that.